# PHP closure: use keyword with function definition: object argument to use: parameter not copied

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, anonymous

The following code is a slightly modified version of an example from

[PHP Manual -> Language Reference -> Functions -> Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

The example mentions, but doesn't explain, why you cannot pass a PHP object by value
to the argument list after the use keyword in a function. In paricular, why isn't
the object passed by value in the use parameter list as in the following code
copied inside the $broken anonymous function just like can be done with scalar values?

Here is the code:

```
class MyClass {

  function doSomething() { echo "HELLO WORLD\n"; }

}

$myInstance = null;

$broken = function() use ($myInstance) {
    if(!empty($myInstance)) $myInstance->doSomething();
    else echo "\$myInstance is empty.\n";
    var_dump($myInstance); // NULL
};

$working = function() use (&$myInstance) {
    if(!empty($myInstance)) $myInstance->doSomething();
    else print "\$myInstance is empty.\n";
};

$myInstance = new MyClass();

$myInstance->doSomething();    // Outputs HELLO WORLD.
$broken();                     // Outputs $myInstance is empty. NULL
$working();                    // Outputs HELLO WORLD.
```

Thanks.

---

This is an update to my post following the reply I received from Valentin Rodygin.
If the $myInstance = null; line is commented out I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: myInstance in C:\xampp\htdocs\myexamples\use.php on line 11
```

Basically, when the parameter to the use keyword is passed by value it is copied at the
time the function that makes use of the use keyword is defined, not when the function
that makes use of the use keyword is called. The same is true for variables which are
passed by reference, but since they are passed by reference, any later modification
to such variable prior to invoking the function will make the updated value of such
a variable available inside the function.

Thanks.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/OYrM9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your code.

```
$myInstance = null;
$broken = function() use ($myInstance) {
    if(!empty($myInstance)) $myInstance->doSomething();
    else echo "\$myInstance is empty.\n";
    var_dump($myInstance); // NULL
};
```

At this moment, you've already created a closure and passed there a **copy** of the variable and it's NULL.

```
$working = function() use (&$myInstance) {
    if(!empty($myInstance)) $myInstance->doSomething();
    else print "\$myInstance is empty.\n";
};
```

And here you passed a reference, so later, when you've instantiated $myInstance, it became accessible in the closure.

Comment: Thanks. I've update my post to reflect the explanation you gave in your answer. Regards.